# OSX SSH tunnel from remote port to local

Tags: macos, ssh, portforwarding

I've created SSH tunnels in the past, but I'm having trouble on OSX. I'm looking to take a website's port 80, and direct it to my localhost:8080. When I run this command

```
ssh -L 8080:<cloud_ip_address>:80 root@<cloud_ip_address> -N
```

I get the default apache 'it works!' page.

Why am I not getting the port 80 of the remote machine (which is running a web app)?

**UPDATE**
I still do not have a solution yet, but I have some more information. The page I am getting is the default page in /var/www/html but I am serving a Flask app which does not have static pages.

Answer (score 3):

Because `HTTP` protocol contains not only the IP address, but also the hostname (the URL you type into your browser), which differs between the `<cloud_hostname>` and `localhost`. The easiest way to trick it is to create `/etc/hosts` (there will be some OSX alternative -- search ...) entry redirecting the hostname of your remote machine to localhost.

```
127.0.0.1 <cloud_hostname>
```

But note that in this case you will not be able to access the remote machine using the hostname!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I still get the default ubuntu apache page from the cloud server. I've read that OSX obscures some common SSH functions. I've asked this in, possibly, a more appropriate forum: [SU Forum](http://superuser.com/questions/1168824/forwarding-remote-port-80-to-osx-localhost-port)

Comment: after doing some digging, I have gotten some understanding (but still no solution) of what's going on. The page I am receiving is the default page in /var/www/HTML. So my Flask app route is not being seen as the default route. Regardless, no answer on how to direct the tunnel to the Flask App.